# Need help converting a query from PostgreSQL to CakePHP

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, postgresql-9.4

I have a query that works well when i execute it in my PostgreSQL database but I can't make it work in my controller.

This is the query:

`SELECT id, nume, prenume FROM cirrus.personal
    WHERE unaccent(nume) ILIKE '%bala%' OR unaccent(prenume) ILIKE '%bala%';`

The special thing about this query is that i use the `unaccent()` extension of my PostgreSQL database because i need it when i search for the names of a persons with a term that has to be insensitive for special characters like `'a'` and `'ă'`.

My present query in `PersonalController.php` is the following :

```
$personalTemp = $this->Personal->find('all', ['fields' => ['id', 'nume', 'prenume']])
                ->where(['OR' => [['Personal.nume ilike' => "%" . $term . "%"], 
                                  ['Personal.prenume ilike' => "%" . $term . "%"]]]);
```

I have tried multiple ways of placing `unaccent()` in this query, like adding it to `unaccent(Personal.nume)` or to `"unaccent(%" . $term . "%)"` but none of these work the same as the SQL query I am trying to accomplish.

Any advice would be gladly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have managed to create the desired query in my controller. It looks like this:

```
    $personalTemp = $this->Personal->find('all', ['fields' => [
                                'id' => 'id',
                                'nume' => 'nume',
                                'prenume' => 'prenume'
                                ]])
                        ->where(['OR' => [ 
     ['public.unaccent(nume) ilike public.unaccent(\'%'. $term . '%\') '],
     ['public.unaccent(prenume) ilike public.unaccent(\'%'. $term . '%\') ']]]);`
```

But now CakePhp is having trouble recognizing the `unaccent()` function. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `unaccent` extension is set to `public` schema.
Try setting it to your schema:

```
ALTER EXTENSION unaccent
  SET SCHEMA your_schema;
```

According to [Postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterextension.html)

> SET SCHEMA
>
> ```
> This form moves the extension's objects into another schema.
> ```

Comment: Yes, Thank you! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $this->Personal->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Personal.id',
            'Personal.nume',
            'Personal.prenume'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                'unaccent(nume) LIKE \'%bala%\''
                'unaccent(nume) LIKE \'%bala%\''
            )
        )
    ))
```

Comment: Your method of approaching the query was helpful cause it led me closer to the correct query format that I wanted, and for that I thank you very much. But I cannot mark is as an answer yet cause I havențt fully finished my problem.

Comment: Given that `bala` is possible user input (see `$term` in the question), this is a possible SQL injection vulnerability! You better use proper `key => value` notation, or safe expressions!

Comment: yes you are right maybe he should change it to
'unaccent(nume)' => "%bala%"

Comment: Yes, you are right and I have already changed so that it can match my requirements. See the edit I have added to my post for the final form of the query.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you need to use bind to avoid problems with sql injection

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#binding-values

try this

```
$orWhere = [
            "unaccent(nume) ilike '%'||unaccent(:search)||'%' ",
            "unaccent(prenume) ilike '%'||unaccent(:search)||'%' ",
        ];
$qry->bind(':search', $search, 'string');
$qry->where(['OR' => $orWhere]);
```